# Deploying with cargo and an invalid SSL certificate

Tags: deployment, ssl, cargo

My test Tomcat 6 server has a self signed certificate. The manager webapp is accessible only via SSL, with this self signe certificate. When I try to deploy with the cargo-maven2-plugin, I get the error :

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I could probably add the certificate to the default Java keystore, but I would like to keep deployment as portable as possible and not require that everybody who needs to deploy the app to install the certificate. I would like to deploy the app by just having a checkout of the project, configuring the password to the app server and running Maven.

I could not find in the cargo documentation a way to ignore invalid certificates.

Can you point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly ignorant on cargo specifically, but I've used this code to allow bad certs without errors in Java before, and it should work for you.  Note that it's super insecure, but then again if you want to ignore invalid certs then pretty much any implementation is going to be super insecure.

http://ctasada.blogspot.com/2010/11/httpclient-use-self-signed-certificates.html